# Resizing 2 partitions (NTFS and ReiserFS3)

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, ntfs, reiserfs

When creating a Win7 and Gentoo setup I miss allocated the space needed for Windows and Linux. I have a 320 gb drive and created a 40gb partition on Win7 and used the rest of the space on Linux. Now I need about 70gbs on the NTFS partition. Are there any tools that will shrink the ReiserFS3 partition? (It is using about 80gbs and has the reset free), while growing the NTFS partition?

If I have to clone, does the tool copy freespace inside the image? I would prefer this not happen as that I'm sort on backup space. [I can handle a 100-150gb of images, but I can't copy the entire HD]

Comment: might consider switching to an fs with continuing support.. now that Hans is in prison, it seems improbable that ReiserFS will progress :(